want to what's wrong in my contract as i can't able to call my deposit function
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer as SplTransfer};
// use solana_program::system_instruction;
use solana_program::{account_info::AccountInfo, pubkey::Pubkey};
declare_id!("");
#[program]
pub mod bridge {
use super::*;
pub fn deposit(
    ctx: Context<TransferSpl>,
    amount: u64
) -> Result<()> {
    assert!(amount > 0, "No amount to transfer");
    let destination = &ctx.accounts.to_ata;
    let source = &ctx.accounts.from_ata;
    let token_program = &ctx.accounts.token_program;
    let authority = &ctx.accounts.from;

    // Transfer tokens from taker to initializer
    let cpi_accounts = SplTransfer {
        from: source.to_account_info(),
        to: destination.to_account_info(),
        authority: authority.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info();

    token::transfer(CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts), amount)?;

    let this_account = &mut ctx.accounts.reciept;
    this_account.count += 1;
    this_account.user = ctx.accounts.signer.key();
    this_account.amount = amount;
    Ok(())
}


pub fn claim(
    ctx: Context<TransferSpl>,
    _to: Pubkey
) -> Result<()> {
    let this_account = &mut ctx.accounts.reciept;
    let destination = &ctx.accounts.to_ata;
    let source = &ctx.accounts.from_ata;
    let token_program = &ctx.accounts.token_program;
    let authority = &ctx.accounts.from;

    let cpi_accounts = SplTransfer {
        from: source.to_account_info(),
        to: destination.to_account_info(),
        authority: authority.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info();

    token::transfer(CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts), this_account.amount)?;
    Ok(())
}

}
#[derive(Accounts)]
//#[instruction()]
pub struct TransferSpl<'info> {
pub from: Signer<'info>,
#[account(mut)]
pub from_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
pub to_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
#[account(
    init_if_needed,
    payer = signer,
    space = 500,
    seeds = [],
    bump
)]
pub reciept: Account<'info, TransactionInfo>,
#[account(mut)]
pub signer: Signer<'info>,
pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

}
#[account]
pub struct TransactionInfo {
pub count: u128,
pub user: Pubkey,
pub amount: u64,
pub ok: u8
}
